# Make an index unique after creation in Titan

Tags: titan, gremlin

If I create an index according to the docs (http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.5.4/indexes.html) without making it unique is it possible to make it unique after? I have not added any vertices or edges to the graph, just created the index.

Something like:

```
index = mgmt.getGraphIndex('name')
index.unique()
```

I am using the Gremlin console to make these changes.

Is it possible to do this somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a documented limitation of Titan.

Ref : http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.5.0/limitations.html
      section - 14.2.1. Unable to Drop Indices

Since no vertices or edges are added to graph, try the below gremlin command.

```
 g.V.remove() or g.V.each{g.removeVertex(it)}

  g.commit()
```

Then try to create the indexes again with .unique().
If still unable to re-create the indices, try to clean storage-backend.
In case of cassandra `"DROP Keyspace titan;"`
This must definitely work,I have tried in Titan 0.4 and worked.